# How to call REST APIs on Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

How can I call APIs on Azure portal?

I have some requirements that need to call rest APIs on Azure Portal in my code. I noticed that some actions can be done on the Portal but there are no associated API or SDK provided by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some findings here.
For instance, let’s say , I want to enable “application proxy” in AAD : 
[image]

As we all know ,there is no SDK, powershll or APIs published by Microsoft officially, we can do this function on Azure portal manually but unable to do it using code.

For this situation , we can try to fetch its request to have a try.

First , let’s try to fetch its whole request :
[image]

We can get all infos about this request so that we can call this API via code. The only problem  we should solve is getting the proper access token.

To get an access token, we should know what resource we need. So we should analyze the access token in the request we just captured :
[image]

So the resource we need should be : 74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6

So we should request access token in this way :

Request URL:

```
post https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant ID>/oauth2/token
```

Request Header:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Request Body:

```
resource=74658136-14ec-4630-ad9b-26e160ff0fc6&client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2&grant_type=password&username=<Azure admin username(URL encoded)>&password=<admin password(URL encoded)>
```

With this request, we are able to get an access token to call the API we want.

Btw, If you’re Microsoft partner, I find a free channel to solve azure queries: https://aka.ms/devchat. They support online chat and email.